# Why does DragEvent.ACTION DROP gets called twice

Tags: android

When using a DragListenerClass :

```
protected class myDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(final View v, DragEvent event) {

        final int action = event.getAction();   

        switch (action) {

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: 
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED :
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                Log.d("DROP", "DROP");

                if((ViewGroup) dragView.getParent() != null)
                    ((ViewGroup) dragView.getParent()).removeView(dragView);
                main_layout.addView(dragView,currentViewIndexUnderDragView);

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:    
                break;                          
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

the drag listener class is used like this :

```
final myDragEventListener dragListener = new myDragEventListener();     
main_container.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
```

And the drag is started like this:

```
onLongClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {                

            v.startDrag(null,new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);               

            main_layout.removeView(v);
            dragListener.dragView = v;              

            return true;
        }
    };
```

Problem is that the drop is called twice and I have no idea why or what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual event `DragEvent.ACTION_DROP` only happens once, but you are using the same code for three different events. `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` happens after the drag has ended (either a drop or exit action) and executes your code again. I would recommend splitting that out to its own `case` or removing it altogether.

You can read about all the action behaviors here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DragEvent.html

Comment: Your right ! I missed a break; in the ended action, only drop and exited should add the view. thanks !